# VBA - Excel : spot a specific number in a column

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have in my excel file a column filed with words and numbers like this: 
[image]

My goal is to have my program analyzing the elements of this column. Right now, I am trying to identify the postal code which is, in my case, a four figures numbers (here 1121).

So I want to loop from the first to the last element, and have a matching method saying something like "if this element is a number and has four figures, then...". I don't know if this is possible in VBA and my researches have been quite unproductive as google-ing my key words for this query leads to results which doesn't relate to what I'm doing.

I guess the structure would look like this :

```
For i = 2 To lRowD
Range("D" & i).Activate
myResult = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 'SOMETHING IDENTIFYING FOUR FIGURES NUMBERS

If myResult Then 'if Metro Manila in the address
  Range("A20").Value = ActiveCell.Value  'put the Zip Code in another cell
Else

End If
 Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
Sub ProcessColumn()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRowD As Long
Dim cell As Excel.Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    lRowD = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("D2:D" & lRowD).Cells
        If Len(cell.Value) = 4 And (Val(cell.Value) = cell.Value) Then
            ws.Range("A20").Value = cell.Value  'put the Zip Code in another cell
        Else
            'do something else?
        End If
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I just realized that will allow decimal numbers.  I can fix it when I'm at a computer.

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for the answer, it does the trick perfectly! Don't worry about decimal numbers, elements in my column will only be element from addresses so no decimal numbers involved. Thanks!